Ansible: Telnet module hangs after connecting
I am using the telnet module – Executes a low-down and dirty telnet command.
This is my playbook:
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no

  vars:

    telnet_link: "x.x.x.200"
    telnet_port: "5001"

  tasks:

    - name: Configure Static IP via Telnet
      ansible.netcommon.telnet:
        host: "{{ telnet_link }}"
        port: "{{ telnet_port }}"
        crlf: true
        send_newline: true
        prompts:
          - '[alpine:~#]'
        command:
          - echo "yes"

The Ansible playbook cannot resolve the command, and I think it is caused either by the carriage return or the alpine:~# prompt. See below:
me@my-vm:~/lab$ telnet x.x.x.200 5001
Trying x.x.x.200...
Connected to x.x.x.200.
Escape character is '^]'.
                           <- I press enter here
alpine:~#
alpine:~#
telnet> quit
Connection closed.

What I want is to give a static IP to my Alpine in GNS3 lab, so telnet link is more or less the only way.
I am open to alternatives, thank you a lot!
